# SELECT значений одного поля 'as' два разных значения в одном запросе

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица `users`, в которой хранятся данные о пользователях.
Пользователи оказывают услуги друг другу и оставляют отзывы друг о друге. Есть поля `user_id`, `photo`.
В одном запросе нужно вытащить `users.photo as user1` и `users.photo as user2`, зная `user_id` обоих участников. Это возможно?

Comment: Вопрос допускает разные толкования и прямо говоря непонятен. Структура полей понятна, что хотите получить - нет.

Comment: Может быть, эти две строчки (с user_id 1 и 2) имеют поле с общим внешним ключом? По какому-то же принципу вы выделяете именно этих двух пользователей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формально под ваше описание подпадает бестолковый запрос:

```
SELECT
  `ID`,
  (SELECT photo FROM `b_user` WHERE id = 1) AS photo1,
  (SELECT photo FROM `b_user` WHERE id = 3) AS photo2

FROM `b_user`
WHERE ID IN (1,3)
```

Или - на JOIN'ах, если вы понимаете этот синтаксис (не уверен судя по тому, как задан вопрос):

```
SELECT
  u1.photo AS photo1,
  u2.photo AS photo2
FROM b_user u1
INNER JOIN b_user u2
WHERE u1.id = 1
AND u2.id = 3;
```

Но мне кажется, что это вообще не то, что вы хотите.

Я предлагаю вам описать задачу, которую вы хотите решить своим вопросом. См. тут: [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy).

Comment: Сработал бестолковый запрос!)

Comment: Чесслово, лучше бы вам подошёл вариант Akina. Там есть логика, там понятно, что и для чего берётся, понятна задача, которую вы решаете. А так я чувствую себя человеком, который помогает гвозди микроскопом заколачивать. Всё же -- на досуге подумайте, какую вы метазадачу решаете, возможно, захотите спросить на so и узнать другие варианты, помимо того, что "сработал".

Comment: На самом деле, весь запрос гораздо сложнее, а мы помним главное правило программиста - если код работает, ничего не трогать!) простите меня за ваши чувства)

Answer (score 2):

> Пользователи оказывают услуги друг другу и оставляют отзывы друг о друге.

Скорее всего, это фиксится в некоей таблице

```
CREATE TABLE `Услуги_И_Отзывы` (`Кто`, `Кому`, `прочие_поля`)
```

Ну тады

```
SELECT u1.photo as user1, u2.photo as user2, `Всё остальное`
FROM `Услуги_И_Отзывы` main
   , users u1
   , users u2
WHERE main.`Кто` = u1.user_id
  AND main.`Кому` = u2.user_id
/* AND всё остальное */
```

Comment: Вот да, я подозреваю, что у топикстартера именно этот вариант с таблицей, не описанной в вопросе - потому и предложил озвучить исходную проблему, которую пытается решить.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  u1.photo AS user1,
  u2.photo AS user2
FROM users u1
CROSS JOIN users u2
WHERE u1.user_id = 1
AND u2.user_id = 2;
```